# 'System shutdown already initiated' error message in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, window.open

I am using JavaScript to launch to an external browser window using `window.open()`. On initial launch from my application the window opens fine in Internet Explorer 11, however, when I close the window and try to open it immediately again I get the following error:

[image: Error message 'A system shutdown has already been scheduled.']

If I wait ~10 seconds and try it again after closing the window, the error does not appear.

Has anybody here see this error before and knows what might be causing it? Is there a possible solution? I've tried disabling the popup blocker but to no avail.

Comment: Here's a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23994477/createobject-randomly-throws-a-system-shutdown-has-already-been-scheduled-erro) with the same error but in vbscript/vba - looks like the solution there was to just catch the error and retry the operation.

Comment: Thanks James for the very quick response.I tried this, but the concern is that the time is too long between when the user initiates a click and when the window.open() command finally executes again.

Comment: This is a bad reuse of a standard COM error code; it's not that a system shutdown is in process, but instead that a cross-process COM broker is shutting down. (I recognize that this doesn't solve your problem)